# Convert callback hell to deferred object

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

***Background***: So, I have a pretty big project with a lot of API functions. I'm thinking of completely moving to coroutines, but as they are implemented as `Callback` and not `Deferred`, I can not use them efficiently. For instance: I would like to do `apiCallOne()`, `apiCallTwo()` and `apiCallThree()` async and call `.await()` to wait till the last request is completed before changing UI.

Now the project is structured like this:

At the very bottom (or top) is `ApiService.java`:

```
interface ApiService {
    @GET("...")
    Call<Object> getData();
    ...
}
```

Then I have a `ClientBase.java`:
function `createRequest()` is main function for parsing retrofit response.

```
void getUserName(String name, ApiCallback<ApiResponse<...>> callback) {
    createRequest(ApiService.getData(...), new ApiCallback<ApiResponse<?>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ServiceResponse response) {
            callback.onResult(response);
        }
    });
}

private void createRequest(Call call, final ApiCallback<ApiResponse<?>> callback) {

    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, retrofit2.Response response) {
                //heavy parsing
            }

            // return request results wrapped into ApiResponse object
            callback.onResult(new ApiResponse<>(...));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            // return request results wrapped into ApiResponse object
            callback.onResult(...);
        }
    });
}
```

`ApiCallback` and `ApiResponse` looks like this:

```
public interface ApiCallback<T> {
    void onResult(T response);
}

public class ApiResponse<T> {
    private T mResult;
    private ServiceError mError;
    ...
}
```

So, before all of this, I have also `ApiClient.java` which uses `ClientBase.createRequest()`:

```
public void getUserName(String name, ApiCallback<ApiResponse<..>> callback) {
    ClientBase.getUserName(secret, username, new ServiceCallback<ServiceResponse<RegistrationInvite>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ServiceResponse<RegistrationInvite> response) {
            ...
            callback.onResult(response);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, this is very, very bad. How can I transfer some of this code at least to make sure, that `ApiClient.java` function return `Deferred` objects? (I'm willing to create another wrapper class for this)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So in general, a simple way to do this is to return a `suspendCancellableCoroutine` from a suspending function, which you can then complete asynchronously. So in your case, you might write something like:

```
suspend fun getUserName(name: String): ApiResponse<...> {
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        createRequest(ApiService.getData(...), new ApiCallback<ApiResponse<...>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(ApiResponse<...> response) {
                continuation.resume(response)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You basically return the equivalent of a `SettableFuture` and then mark it complete when you get success or failure. There's also `continueWithException(Throwable)` if you want to handle errors via exception handling.

**That said:**

Since you're using Retrofit, I would recommend just adding in the [retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter) dependency which adds in this support for you natively.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can first convert `ApiService.java` to `ApiService.kt` in Kotlin:

   ```
   interface ApiService {
       @GET("…")
       fun getData ( … : Call<Object>)
   }
   ```

   To change the return type of your service methods from `Call` to `Deferred`, you can modify the above line to:

   ```
   fun getData ( … : Deferred<Object>)
   ```

---

2. To set up the request for parsing the retrofit response in Kotlin, you can reduce it to a few lines in Kotlin.

   In your `onCreate()` in `override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){` in `MainActivity.kt`:

   ```
   val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
   // Below to add Retrofit 2 ‘s Kotlin Coroutine Adapter for Deferred
             .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory()) 
             .baseUrl(“YOUR_URL”)
             .build()

   val service = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java) 
   // Above using :: in Kotlin to create a class reference/ member reference

   val apiOneTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.api_one_text_view)
   // to convert cast to findViewById with type parameters
   ```

---

3. I don’t know the use case for your API, but if your API is going to return a long text chunk, you can also consider using a suggested approach at the bottom of this post.

   I included on an approach to pass the text computation to `PrecomputedTextCompat.getTextFuture`, which according to Android documentation, is a helper for `PrecomputedText` that returns a future to be used with `AppCompatTextView.setTextFuture(Future)`.

---

4. Again, inside your `MainActivity.kt`:

   ```
   // Set up a Coroutine Scope
   GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){

   val time = measureTimeMillis{ 
   // important to always check that you are on the right track 

   try {

       initialiseApiTwo()

       initialiseApiThree()

       val createRequest = service.getData(your_params_here)

       apiOneTextView.text=”Your implementation here with api details using ${createRequest.await().your_params_here}”

    } catch (exception: IOException) {

          apiOneTextView.text=”Your network is not available.”
       }
     }
       println(“$time”) 
       // to log onto the console, the total time taken in milliseconds taken to execute 

   }
   ```

   > **Deferred** + **Await** = to suspend to await result, does not block main UI thread

---

5. For your `initializeApiTwo()` & `initializeApiThree()`, you can use `private suspend fun` for them, using the similar `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){`... & `val createRequestTwo = initializeApiTwo()`, where: `private suspend fun initializeApiTwo() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {` // coroutine scope, & following the same approach as outlined in discussion point 2.

---

6. When I used the method outlined above, my implementation took *1863ms*.

   To further streamline this method (from sequentially to concurrently), you can add the following modifications in yellow, to move to **Concurrent** using **Async** (same code from point discussion 4.), which in my case, gave a *50% time improvement* & cut duration to *901ms*.

   > According to Kotlin documentation, ***Async*** returns a ***Deferred*** – a light-weight non-blocking future that represents a promise to provide a result later. You can use ***.await()*** on a deferred value to get its eventual result.

   Inside your `MainActivity.kt`:

   ```
   // Set up a Coroutine Scope
   GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){

   val time = measureTimeMillis{ 
   // important to always check that you are on the right track 

   try {
   ```

   > val apiTwoAsync = **async** { initialiseApiTwo() }
   >
   > val apiThreeAsync = **async** { initialiseApiThree() }
   >
   > val createRequest = **async** { service.getData(your_params_here) }
   >
   > val dataResponse = createRequest.await()
   >
   > apiOneTextView.text=”Your implementation here with api details using ${dataResponse.await().your_params_here}”

   ```
    } catch (exception: IOException) {

          apiOneTextView.text=”Your network is not available.”
       }
     }
       println(“$time”) 
       // to log onto the console, the total time taken in milliseconds taken to execute 

   }
   ```

   To find out more on composing suspending functions in this section, you can visit this section on *Concurrent using Async* provided by Kotlin's documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html#concurrent-using-async).

---

7. Suggested Approach for handling `PrecomputedTextCompat.getTextFuture`:

   ```
   if (true) {
      (apiOneTextView as AppCompatTextView).setTextFuture(
         PrecomputedTextCompat.getTextFuture(
             apiOneTextView.text,
             TextViewCompat.getTextMetricsParams(apiOneTextView), null)
    )
   }
   ```

Hope this is helpful.