# Retrofit 2 Request works in Postman but not in App

Tags: android, kotlin, postman, retrofit2, response

I have the following code which makes an API call to get Addresses from Postcode.

```
fun getAddressFromPostCode(postCode: String): List<Address>{

    val trimmedPostCode = postCode.replace("\\s".toRegex(),"").trim()
    val dataBody = JSONObject("""{"postcode":"$trimmedPostCode"}""").toString()
    val hmac = HMAC()
    val hmacResult = hmac.sign(RequestConstants.CSSecretKey, dataBody)
    val body = JSONObject("""{"data":$dataBody, "data_signature":"$hmacResult"}""")


    val url = RequestConstants.URL

    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val api:GetAddressAPIService = retrofit.create(GetAddressAPIService ::class.java)
    var myList = emptyList<Address>()
    val myCall: Call<GetAddressResponse> = api.getAddress(body)

    myCall.enqueue(object : Callback<GetAddressResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<GetAddressResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.d("RegistrationInteractor", "Something went wrong", t)
            Log.d("RegistrationInteractor", call.toString())
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<GetAddressResponse>?, response: Response<GetAddressResponse>?) {
            // Success response
            myList = response!!.body()!!.addresses
        }

    })
    return myList
}
```

And here's where I make the call:

```
interface GetAddressAPIService {
@Headers("Accept: application/json; Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("postcode_search.php")
    fun getAddress(@Body dataBody: JSONObject): Call<GetAddressResponse>
```

}
The GetAddressResponse looks like this and seems to be correct:
data class GetAddressResponse(
val success: Int,
val addresses: List
)

The databody is {"data":{"postcode":"M130EN"},"data_signature":"*long data signature*"} and when I run this in Postman I get a list of addresses, but when I run it in the app I get a 200 OK response but no addresses. Any ideas why?

Comment: If your request is fine, then the issue is that the method is async but you always return an empty list.  I solved this issue in the next post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60446998/get-the-result-of-retrofit-async-call/60447258#60447258  There are more options, but in your case, you could to use an interface and avoid the livedata, or use livedata too, suspend func...

Comment: Check `GetAddressResponse`. Does it has correct structure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert callback hell to deferred object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626871/convert-callback-hell-to-deferred-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is returning but `enqueue` is async so that is not guaranteed to happen before the return. If you read the `enqueue` there is a callback there, which means it is gonna `call` `back` after is ready, since it is an HTTP request then that takes some time and it is finished after the return.

You have 2 alternatives, add the `Callback<GetAddressResponse>` as an argument or any other callback as an argument, or you can make it suspend.

#### Callback

Coroutines are the recommended way of doing things now so this is no longer considered a good practice.

```
fun getAddressFromPostCode(postCode: String, callback: Callback<GetAddressResponse): List<Address>{
    ...
    myCall.enqueue(callback)

}
```

The calling class has to implement the callback and pass it as an argument. You can make that more kotlin way by using a lambda:

```
fun getAddressFromPostCode(postCode: String, callback: (items: List<Address> -> Unit))
    ...
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<GetAddressResponse>?, response: Response<GetAddressResponse>?) {
            callback(response...)
        }

}
```

So that makes the calling class use it this way

```
yourClass.getAddressFromPostCode(postalCode) { -> items
    //do your thing with items
}
```

#### Coroutines

You can transform it to *linear code* by using suspend functions:

```
//make it return optional to know if it was failure
suspend fun getAddressFromPostCode(postCode: String): List<Address>? {
    ...
    return try {
        myCall.invoke().result?.body()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }

}
```

And then the calling class has to use it like this:

```
    lifeCycleScope.launch {
        val addresses = yourClass.getAddressFromPostCode(postalCode)
        //do your thing on the UI with the addresses maybe pass it to an adapter
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused what `myCall.invoke().result?.body()` is trying to do? I'm not able to resolve the reference invoke()

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing here is asynchronously data fetching, while returning immediately from function.

In code you provided, `myCall.enqueue` call is asynchronous and once it's done, it invokes `onFailure` or `onResponse`, depending if the request is failed or not. On the last line of `getAddressFromPostCode` function, you return `myList` value, which is still empty in that case, because `onResponse` has not been called yet.

I can suggest to get familiar with [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html), which would make this code easier to reason about, while handling asynchronous work. Or you could simply provide a callback function to `getAddressFromPostCode` to be called once the request is done or failed.