# Why is my retrofit call returning null when it works on postman?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, retrofit2

I'm trying to use Retrofit with the pokeapi (https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/) and it isn't working, I don't get what i'm doing wrong, since I already tested the call on Postman and it is not working

This is my code so far:

Retrofit Client

```
object RetrofitClient {

    private const val BASE_URL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/"

    private val retrofit: Retrofit by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    fun <T> createService(serviceClass: Class<T>): T {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass)
    }
}
```

PokeApiService

```
interface PokeApiService {

    @GET("pokemon/{id}")
    fun getPokemon(@Path("id") pokemonId: Int): Response<Pokemon>

    @GET("pokemon-species")
    fun getMaxPokemonCount(): Response<PokemonSpeciesResponse>
}
```

This are my data classes

```
data class Pokemon(
    val name: String,
    val types: List<PokemonType>
)

data class PokemonType(
    val slot: Int,
    val type: Type
)

data class Type(
    val name: String
)

data class PokemonSpeciesResponse(
    val count: Int
)
```

This is the code is returning null (should return max pokemon number)

```
    private fun getMaxPokemonCount(): Int? {
            val response = pokeApiService.getMaxPokemonCount()
        try {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("Test", "Response: $response")
                val count = response.body()?.count
                return count
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("Test", "Status code: ${response.code()}")
        }
        return null
    }
```

Finally, here is what GET returns on Postman with pokemon-species

```xml
{
    "count": 1017,
    "next": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species?offset=20&limit=20",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "bulbasaur",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/1/"
        },
        {
            "name": "ivysaur",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/2/"
        },
        {
            "name": "venusaur",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/3/"
        },
        {
            "name": "charmander",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/4/"
        },
        {
            "name": "charmeleon",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/5/"
        },
        {
            "name": "charizard",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/6/"
        },
```

(The xml goes on until the limit, in postman the default is 20)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrofit 2 Request works in Postman but not in App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572623/retrofit-2-request-works-in-postman-but-not-in-app)

Comment: Maybe inside your query, it's not ID it's name

Comment: You're logging the response. What does the response say?

Comment: That does not answer my question at all, since I am using that practices in my code
Also, the query is not the problem, since i'm having problems with the other query, not that one

Comment: @Tenfour04 since it's inside the response.isSuccessful it doesn't even get called, the response is not successful

Comment: You should log the response code to know what happened. Note, your call is not returning null. It's returning a Response object. Your function is returning null when it doesn't get a successful response.

Comment: @IvanWooll, it is not a duplicate of that question. They are making a synchronous call, not using `enqueue`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 My log refuses to print anything inside that method, but I know for a fact my code is passing through there because if I add a Debug point, it stops there, it is so weird.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ok, I discovered something, in the method getMaxPokemonCount(), in the line
`val response = pokeApiService.getMaxPokemonCount()`, it exits the method after that line, it basically ignores anything below that line, I don't get why it does that...

Comment: Set more break points. A method can't be exited from a line that doesn't return or throw. If you get a response that is not successful, you are ignoring it and not logging it and then returning null. Why not move your log out of the if statement to before the if statement?

Comment: @Tenfour04 it's giving out this exception;

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Response<com.example.pokedescifrarcompose.service.PokemonSpeciesResponse>`

Comment: Are you creating the call adapter? I don't see it in your code. Are you calling `createService(...)` with your `PokeApiService`?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Yeah, i'm creating it in the Repository where the method `getMaxPokemonCount()`is, this is the line: `private val pokeApiService: PokeApiService = RetrofitClient.createService(PokeApiService::class.java)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a 'suspend' on my Service, i'm using retrofit 2.9.0

This won't work

```
interface PokeApiService {

    @GET("pokemon/{id}")
    fun getPokemon(@Path("id") pokemonId: Int): Response<Pokemon>

    @GET("pokemon-species")
    fun getMaxPokemonCount(): Response<PokemonSpeciesResponse>
}
```

This is working

```
interface PokeApiService {

    @GET("pokemon/{id}")
    suspend fun getPokemon(@Path("id") pokemonId: Int): Response<Pokemon>

    @GET("pokemon-species")
    suspend fun getMaxPokemonCount(): Response<PokemonSpeciesResponse>
}
```